# How do I code a php script to run on a paged sql query every hour

Tags: php, pagination, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I have a large database - and I need to set up a cron job that would run scheduled tasks on the data. The thing is that the table in question has like over 100'000 entries and so I need to set up my cron job so it runs on 1000 entries every 30 minutes picking the next page of entries on the next cron job run.

I understand that inorder to do this right I'll have to store somewhere the last page of entries that have been accessed / worked on - however I'm not so sure whats the best and easiest way to do this. I'm working on a Laravel based application here.

Comment: Why sync a large database though PHP? every linux distro has their own way to add cron jobs and this should be done on OS level and not so much on PHP level.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 : FILE**

One way to implement this is to `store the record number to start with in a file` .
Every 30 minutes , cron will read that file to know which record number it must start with. You can place this file in the same file as your cron file or store it in app folder of laravel.

Eg :

```
Execution 1 :

startIndex.php has content '1'

Cron.php will print records 1 to 1000 and also set startIndex.php content to 1001



Execution 2 :

startIndex.php has content '1001'

Cron.php will print records 1001 to 2000 and also set startIndex.php content to 2001
```

**Method 2 : Database**

Other Way is to store it in database : [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823527/php-function-to-increment-variable-by-1-each-time-script-is-executed)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can do this, here are some that comes to mind.

Create some kind of a temp file, the file with have a the number of runs/the last row.

then each run the php file will use file_get_contents the read that number.
if you choose the number of runs, you just multiply it by 1000 and Limit your query by that.
If you choose the last row, you just LIMIT lastrow,1000.

Once you finished you just update the file with file_put_contents.
depending on what method you choose.

This will be pretty simlpy with a minimum code.

**Example**

```
$lastrow = file_get_contents("lastrow.log");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT..... LIMIT $lastrow,1000");
while(..){
    //Do you code

    $lastrow++;
}

//You can check if have gone trough all of the table and reset $lastrow to 0

file_put_contents("lastrow.log",$lastrow);
```

Different solution:
You can also add a column to the table, the will mark if the row had been worked on or not, and then update it each row. when there are no rows returned at the begging of the file, just reset the column for all rows.