# Increment a variable by 1, everytime the php script is run

Tags: php

I want my variable `$code` to be incremented by 1 everytime, the php script is called. This is my code:

**script.php**:

```
<?php 
    $code = "05000"; /*On first run, the $code will be "05000", 
                       then on second run it will be "05001" and so on and so forth*/
?>
```

Or in other words, I want my `$code` to give a unique value (which should be self incrementing) everytime, the script is called. How can I do that?

Comment: You will need to use some kind of static storage for the current value, this could be saving it to file, or a database for example.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823527/php-function-to-increment-variable-by-1-each-time-script-is-executed) might help

Comment: where do yo want to store the count? in a file? in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a simple file, you can use this ($count = $code for you) :

```
<?php

$storageFile = "storage.txt";

if (!file_exists($storageFile))
{
    file_put_contents($storageFile, "0");
}

$count = file_get_contents($storageFile);
file_put_contents($storageFile, ($count + 1));
```